# false positive when searching registered string for the absence of a text (Ansible)

Tags: ansible

Im getting false positives with a when statement when searching for a not equal conditional in a output register. The reason is because part of the output contains the text that I am searching against but it is in another line. Below is a sample of my code.

```
  tasks:


  - ios_command:
      commands: show run | inc logging host 
      provider: "{{cli}}"

    register: run

  - debug:
      msg: "{{run.stdout_lines}}"
    when: not  run.stdout | join('') | search('192.168.0.60')
```

So what pretty much is happening is that when the return value is 
`"msg": [
        [
            "logging host 192.168.0.27", 
            "logging host 192.168.0.60"
        ]
    ]`

because the 192.168.0.60 is in there it skips the entire task. Can someone help me with a way detect the logging host 192.168.0.27 is in a seperate line of the search?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve.  Are you saying you want to do something with a **line** of `run` when the line doesn't contain 192.168.0.60?

Comment: Im having issues with the output. The when statement is picking up the 192.168.0.60 in the second line and skipping the entire output. I need it to go line by line so that the 192.168.0.27 value can be printed as that value meets the not condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to loop over your `stdout_lines` to check it line by line.

```
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    when: not "192.168.0.60" in item
    with_items: "{{ run.stdout_lines }}"
```